# Number generator: example. 0812-8192-6281-7392 should look like this

Tags: python

I'm making number generator and i tried to f'{random.randint(0000, 9999)}' but still don't know how to make the numbers always start with 0 and be 4 digits so can you guys help?

Comment: Why do you need this 16 digit random number string?

Comment: Show us the code you've written, and where specifically do you need help.

Answer (score 1):

this is an option:

```
from random import randrange

nbr = "-".join(f"{randrange(10_000):04d}" for _ in range(4))
print(nbr)
```

the idea is to create 4 (therefore the `for` loop) 4-digit strings with leading zeros (`f"{...:04d}"`) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) those with `"-"`.

note that this generates strings ("number generator" may be a misleading name...).

details about string formatting can be found in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).